# Possible to pass a Jenkins Parameter (Variable) directly into a shell script?

Tags: shell, jenkins, sh, devops

Currently I have framework which is hosted in GitHub. Inside the framework (Maven) there is an shell .sch script which Jenkins will execute.

I know its possible to pass parameters from Jenkins (Via This project is parameterised option) but is there a way to pass run time parameters from Jenkins into an .SH script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work just like passing any other value to a shell script.

```
sh '''

   yourscript.sh ${PARAM1} ${PARAM2} ${PARAM3}

'''
```